# Arrange 2 DIVs one below another in Antd Collapse Panel Header along with Extras

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I am using [Antd's Collapse](https://3x.ant.design/components/collapse/) and I would like to add 2 text lines one below another in the Collapse's Panel header along with the extra Property to render some Icons etc like below:

```
     <Panel
        header={
          <div>
            <div>This is panel header 1</div>
            <div style={{ fontSize: "10px" }}>This is panel header 1</div>
          </div>
        }
        key="1"
        extra={genExtra()}
      >
```

I can remove the Padding etc to make get the look I need, but the Icons(setting icon on the right) I render as part of getExtra() are messed up. PFA the image below. How can I get it right?

I also tried dividing the complete hearder tab area into different Columns using Row, Col. Even then the Extra icons on the right are messed up.

[image: Image showing the look to Panel]TIA

Answer (score 2):

In the `getIcon`, for the setting `Icon` add the following style property.

```
style={{position: 'absolute', right: '16px', top: '10px'}}
```

OR

If you want to use multiple icons then change .`.ant-collapse-header` class styles as below.

```css
.ant-collapse-header{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Is there a way to not use the absolute position as I put a good number of icons and some text spans on the right and would like to avoid managing positions.

Comment: If you want that way, you should style `.ant-collapse-header` globally. with `.ant-collapse-header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}`

Comment: and remove `style={{position: 'absolute', right: '16px', top: '10px'}}` from icon

Comment: Thanks Ravi, will try and reply. Thanks a ton

Comment: It makes both the contents center. Here is the link to codesandbox, pls advice- https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-boyd-fxtpj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark